# Se puede Tener 2 Bases de datos diferentes en un mismo Servidor?

Tags: sql, servidor, mariadb

Buenos días  estoy empezando proyectos con base de datos de manera autodidacta jeje bueno al grano..

Tengo  una duda sobre tener 2 bases de datos diferentes en un mismo servidor
 uno es una base datos en tiempo real donde utilizare RethinkDB para una aplicación bien pero solo es para la aplicación

pero si quiero utilizar una base  SQL o como mariaDB para aplicación web ya sea para mostrar algún proyecto  etc.
puedo Tener estas dos bases de datos diferentes en el mismo servidor?  no interfiere en  los puertos que ello utilizan o el Ip  ?

Comment: si se puede tener dos bases en un mismo servidor.

Comment: Amigo 2 cosas, lo primero es que estas haciendo una pregunta demasiado amplia dado que lo que hablas requiere de gran analisis de capacidades por lo que te recomiendo leer [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y modificar tu pregunta. Lo segundo es que de ser posible lo es, ya que deberías realizar 2 clases de tipo conexión a tu proyecto pero debes analizar bien si es realmente necesario hacerlo, ya que podrías crear distintas instancias de BD para lograr tu idea y asi no importa si comparten la IP

Comment: Puedes tener todas las que necesites (si tu hosting te lo permite), lo único que no pueden coincidir en su nombre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu pregunta es un poco confusa, pero intentaré responderte.

> **Si**, se puede tener dos "bases de datos" en el mismo servidor, pero, depende de cómo entiendas tu está frase, comúnmente, se conoce como servidor (cuando hablamos de bases de datos) al motor que corre en nuestra máquina, ya sea MySQL o MariaDB, los cuales en su interior tienen "bases de datos" con tablas, columnas y entradas, la limitación en esto, es que no pueden tener el mismo nombre, por ejemplo, no pueden existir dos bases de datos llamadas "prueba".
>
> **Por otro lado**, si interpretas bases de datos como el motor o el servicio que está corriendo, también se pueden tener varias bases de datos, puedes ejecutar en simultáneo dos o infinitos MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle y demás variantes, pero, aquí hay otra limitación, además de dentro de los motores no poder tener una base de datos con el mismo nombre, cómo el ejemplo anterior de "Prueba", necesitarás utilizar puertos distintos para conectarte, ejemplo a continuación.

Para conectarte a una base de datos requieres por lo general cuatro a cinco datos **Servidor**, **Usuario**, **Contraseña**, **Base de datos**, **Puerto**.
En el supuesto caso de que quieras instalar varias bases de datos, vas a tener que configurarlas en distintos puertos, el puerto por defecto de MySQL es el 3306, puedes utilizar cualquier otro que no interfiera con otro servicio, obviamente teniendo lo necesario, un ordenador, privilegios de administrador y demás cosas, si estás utilizando un hosting, ahí ya es más complicado y te recomendaría hablar o mandar un ticket al soporte técnico debido a que me decís que no tenés mucha formación en bases de datos y demás. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias!,  no todo es local solo son pruebas que hago aun no tengo hosting o es algo solo de educación hahaha pero mi duda era esa de los puertos correcto si interfieren  ademas RethinkDB   es base  no sql  y el otro que si es sql por eso preguntaba si  se podia tener los  dos motores  en un mismo servidor